# Explicit content image filtering/detection

Tags: open-source, software-development, image-processing

I am looking for a software solution for detecting the presence of explicit content in a given image. The filter would essentially give a prediction of the likelihood of explicit content in an image, and if that prediction is high enough, the image is flagged for review from a person.

I am looking for something free/open-source to integrate into different platforms.

Ideas for how this could be accomplished are also welcome. As in, a methodology for detecting this content rather than the final solution.

Some methods that I have thought of/heard of:

1. Reverse image searching and analysis of resultant related keywords (Drawback: costly)
2. Skin color detection with coverage levels to detect nudity. (Drawback: limited only to sexually explicit content)

Comment: Any OS restrictions (must run on X)? From the `open-source` tag it's safe to assume you want the solution to be free-of-charge as well, or is there a budget you might be willing to spend for paid solutions in case there's no free one?

Comment: Considering I am a developer, I want to be able to see the code and make modifications myself. If there is a paid service, linking to it might give me an idea of how to make my own version of it.

Comment: Which still doesn't give the requested details: if you want to make the modifications yourself, that means a selection of programming languages to restrict recommendations to. For a ready-to-use product, it needs a platform it should run on. And, maybe, a budget if one of those is not available without putting some money (though that might be implicitly ruled-out by "open source" when speaking about source-code).

Comment: I didn't give any specific details on programming languages because thats not a factor I am concerned about. To be completely clear: I don't care what platform it is on, I don't care what language it is written in, I'd prefer it was open source but closed source options are also welcome. In terms of budget, I don't plan on spending any money, but it would be just as helpful to know about paid options for the possibility of reverse engineering a service and make my own version. Does that adequately answer your questions?

Comment: Yupp. Though I was hoping to narrow down the scope for better matching recommendations :) Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Google has done much research in this area. Look for their papers which are based on skin detection. It isn't trivial, and I'd expect you to have to pay for it. Otherwise, look into skin detection solutions using opencv. I'd also expect to do some training to identify common shots such as full and partial frontal nudity

Comment: Ahh, I'm close to publishing an open source solution. FYI skin tone based solutions are terrible. There's nude.js as an example implementation of a skin tone based detector but even they admit the algorithm is rather lacking.